# Unsuccessfully using sscanf to read in hexadecimal value

Tags: c, hex, scanf

Here is a much more short version of my code:

```
char token[256];
unsigned int maskval = 0;

//Token gets read in here.

printf("token: %s\n", token);

if (sscanf(token + 2, "%x", &maskval) == 1) {
     //do stuff
} else {
     printf("error: %d, %x\n", maskval, maskval);
}
```

As you can see I am passing hexadecimal strings to the function, reading them into token and using sscanf() to convert the string version of the hexadecimal value into a unsigned int. The string token always begins with "0x", "0X", "Ox", or "OX". The reason for this is because the user will be unable to tell the difference between a 0 or a O when inputting the value (vi displays them the same, graphical). The result I get if I pass it "0x00EE" is:

```
token: 0x00EE
error: 0
```

The problem I believe is whether I pass it something along the lines of "0x00EE" or "OxOOEE" (zero's vs capital o's). Both look identical in vi, and I am not sure if they are handled differently in this scenario. Hopefully I am just doing something really simple and stupid that I overlooked though (that's usually the case). Also, I have tried using

```
maskval = strtol(token, NULL, 16);
```

instead of sscanf() but I get the exact same results.

Any ideas?

Comment: In my ViM, `0` has a dot in it, while `O` doesn't!

Comment: Shouldn't it be `char token[256];`???

Comment: Also, `%x` can read the `0x` part also, so you don't need to write `token+2`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's one mistake:

```
char *token[256];
```

This is a an array of 256 pointers to character (`char *`), not an array of characters.

You meant:

```
char token[256];
```

There should be plenty of compiler warnings from this.

Trying to parse a hexadecimal value from a string beginning something that is not a valid hexadecimal digit will of course fail, for both `sscanf()` and `strtoul()`. You almost sound as if you think the standard functions should consider `'O'` to be hex just because it looks like the digit 0 for you. That is ... not how they've been designed, which I think is fortunate. :) You might want to look into changing your fonts.

You could manually strip the non-conforming prefix. Assuming you *always* have the 2-character prefix, and then *might* have one, you could do:

```
const char *number = token + 2;

while(!isxdigit(*number))
  number++;
/* Now number will point at the first hexadecimal
   digit in token, or '\0' if none were found.
*/
if(sscanf(number, "%x", &maskval) == 1)
  printf("success, got %x\n", maskval);
else
  printf("failed to parse '%s' as hexadecimal number\n", number);
```

Comment: Good answer! Had to fix a few things in your solution, but it works now! Had to change while(isxdigit(*number)) to while(!isxdigit(*number)) and the if(sscanf) statement to evaluate sscanf to 1.